# Building an RSVP system in Rails with has_many, through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Events app in `Rails 5` and I'm trying to build an **RSVP system**.

The functionality that I'm trying to build is that a user can go to the events show page and click an 'rsvp' button. This user will then show up in the events show page under 'users attending this event'. Additionally, the event will also show up on the user's show page - **'this user is attending the following events'.**

I'm pretty new to `Rails` and I'm not really sure how to handle the rsvp button functionality. This is my code so far:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
...
end
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, through: :attendances

end
```

**attendance.rb**

```
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'events#index'

  resources :events do
    resources :users
  end

  resources :users      
end
```

And this is the form on the events show page where I'm trying to add a user to the event

**show.html.erb - events**

```
<%= form_for([@event, @event.users.build] do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.submit "RSVP", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if you need any extra code posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your controller's action find the event and and add the user into the attendance simple as

```
event = Event.find_by_id(params[:event_id])
user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
attendance= event.attendances.create(user_id=>user.id)
```

and when you want to know the users who are going for the event you can find as:

```
users = event.users
```

Comment: In the `EventsController`? Also, is this for the `create` action?

Comment: Actually this should be in attendance create, action is where you want to add the code of join the event for users